# What is the meaning of these progressive gas tap codes?

Tags: gas, tap

I need to replace a leaking progressive gas tap from a Cooktop. The manufacturer doesn't provide spare parts anymore. I found many alternative options. Some look exactly like the defective tap.
But I'm not sure because there are lots of codes on both sides, also there seems to be a color code too.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I noticed in one side there is always this PMAX and a number and an arrow and another number. In the opposite side there is this equal and a letter and 3 other numbers.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The arrow is probably the direction the gas should flow.

Comment: Some of the numbers might relate to orifice size or something. Appliances often have a service manual attached on the surface or behind a panel that a service person would open. Maybe check whether yours any manual tucked inside; it might have pertinent information.

Comment: `gas tap` ... don't  you mean `gas valve`?

Comment: @jsotola OP is in Brazil, so it's likely they use "tap" where we'd use "valve" in the US.